# Issue tracking category in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, issue-tracking

I'd like to know how one can create (and modify) a Category in Issue Tracking.

Answer (score 4):

1. You can edit the existing Category field by navigating to Issue tracking list -> List Settings -> Click on Category column -> Update the text for category in choice field.

[image]

2. You can create new category field by navigating to List Settings -> click on Create column -> select type choice -> add custom category text.